# 360° panorama librarys for ios panoramaGL.a

Tags: panorama-control

Hi I am using this link to implement the panorama 360 view images

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60635/Panorama-360-iPod-Touch-iPhone

I had also followed the steps from the site,but the panoramaGL.a lib file is always missing there.

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The codeproject article is old, please check the las version of PanoramaGL library http://code.google.com/p/panoramagl/ and download HelloPanoramaGL example. If you can read UserGuide in Wiki section.

This last version supports hotspots and other features read README.txt and CHANGES.txt files.